# Why do the best energy star freezers have higher capacity and lower rated power consumption than the best refrigerators?

Tags: energy-efficiency, cooling, usa, food-storage

The title says it all; I'm looking for any qualitative information that can help me.

Freezers: https://www.energystar.gov/productfinder/product/certified-residential-freezers/details/2255167
Refrigerators: https://www.energystar.gov/most-efficient/me-certified-refrigerators/results

Per [this question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/10188/how-does-the-epa-estimate-annual-power-consumption-for-refrigerators), the testing process for refrigerators costs money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it seems logical that a refrigerator would be more efficient since it doesn't have to keep things as cold, there are a few different factors affecting real-world performance.

**Freezers are simpler to operate.**
In a freezer there's only a top end on the temperature range. From [refrigerator manufacturer LG](https://www.lg.com/ca_en/support/product-help/CT20098040-20150106740310) you can see the range in the refrigerator is narrow, but the freezer range is broad:

> [image: Freezer and refrigerator temperature range]

For a freezer, the compressor can run for a while to get the compartment well below zero. During start-up and stopping, the compressor is less efficient, so it makes sense to run it for a while.

But in a refrigerator, if you run the compressor too long, you risk freezing things that shouldn't be frozen.

**Fridges need a "relief" valve.** If a fridge does get too cold, it needs to be able to warm back up again. I suspect this is why the insulation is thinner in the fridge compartment -- if it's too thick and the compartment gets too cold, there's no way to warm it back up. But having thinner insulation means that if the compartment gets a bit too cold, it will naturally warm back up a bit. This allows the thermostat and control system to be simpler (and cheaper).

**Freezers aren't opened as often.**
This part gets to the real-world aspect of Energy Star ratings. It's 11am where I am, and so far I've opened my refrigerator three times: creamer for my coffee, orange juice with breakfast, and an apple for a snack. I've only opened my freezer once to get some frozen fruit for my oatmeal. So the testing criteria likely emulates this real-world usage.

Comment: From my googling, it looks like an important element is that freezers are also just more insulated all around, similar to your "relief" valve point.

Comment: Two further factors are: (1) the fridge linked to is a larger volume than the freezer and (2) it is a top-loading freezer, which means that the heat exchange when the door is  open is far less than for the side-opening fridge. If people would buy top-loading fridges, they could be significantly more efficient.