# What 'average' conditions are used to test the energy usage of freezers for a EU energy label?

Tags: energy-efficiency

I'm orienting myself on buying an extra (small) freezer on top of the limited amount of freezer space I already have in my fridge/freezer combination, so I can more easily cook and store fresh produce that usually comes in 'big' portions, like cabbages, instead of always buying the more expensive (and more unsustainable) pre-cut/washed stuff in little plastic bags. But before I do so, I do want to make sure the costs of the energy it will use and the initial investment won't take years to earn itself back.

I can easily find the estimated energy usage on the EU Energy Labels these appliances are sold with, but I can't find on what kind of usage those labels are based. Any explainer I found states that the number is based on an 'average' usage, which means I'm expecting they are likely to be based on some kind of 'perfect' test conditions, which are unlikely to resemble the actual usage I have planned for it. I want to put this freezer in a shed, which means hot summers and cold (but rarely freezing) winters, and I will probably be opening it at least once a day, more often in summer to get myself some ice cream. I doubt it will always be entirely filled, and I don't plan on keeping around a bunch of styrofoam blocks to fill up any nook/cranny anytime I take something out.

But I can't find anything on Google when searching for 'freezer energy label test conditions' that gives a quick overview of what the used testing conditions would be, which would allow me to compare the result of that test to my expected usage of the freezer and make a more accurate calculation of how fast the freezer will have paid itself off.

**What 'average' conditions are used to test the energy usage of freezers for a EU energy label?**

Comment: This might get you started. When I have a minute I'll see if there's something similar for ISO testing of freezers. https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/a/10464/3379